# Why not using numeric coordinates instead of sf object=POINT?

Tags: r, r-sf, r-leaflet

I want to show points on the map. Those points are represented as coordinates (long/lat) and are stored in a data frame as numerics. I'm wondering if I really need to transform numeric coordinates (lon/lat) to sf object of POINT type. I don't know what benefits of such convertion are. In this example I use numeric coordinates from 2 columns and show them on the map:

```
data(quakes)

leaflet(data = quakes[1:20,]) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(~long, ~lat)
```

Here data frame (quakes) is not spatial, lon/lat are numeric. However, I can do exactly the same converting numeric coordinates to sf POINTs, then show them on a map:

```
coords <- quakes %>%
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("long","lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
  sf::st_geometry()

leaflet(data = coords[1:20,]) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers()
```

Question is: in case of showing points (markers) on the map - should we convert to spatial objects first or just use numeric columns? What's the point of using POINTs at all if I can do exactly the same using numeric lon/lat? Performance issues?

Comment: If you want, you can use points in `tm_dots` in `tmap` rather than the coordinates using `leaflet`.

Comment: Ok, I know that I can use it but what's the difference in using sf POINTs or numeric coordinates (float)? Maybe it's no difference? Or maybe it's all about performance or precision on the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to convert, and if the only purpose of your spatial object is drawing a `{leaflet}` map - i.e. you do no other calculations, statistics, modelling or so on - there is little point in transforming.

The [`{leaflet}` documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html) is quite straigforward about data types supported - `{sf}` objects, `{sp}` objects & regular lat / lon data.frames.

The only - very slight - benefit of using one of the special spatial formats is that you don't need to specify your latitude & longitude mappings in your `addMarker()` call. I wouldn't expect any effect on performance.

Note though that while {leaflet} supports multiple ways of data input it will not be able to process data in projected coordinate systems (eastings and northings).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted to know:)